# mvc3 windows authentication returning 401.0 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ntlm

I am building a local intranet web application which uses the current user's AD credentials to access the system.  My web server is running IIS 7.5 on Server 2008.

My AD is configured with two groups, Users and Admins, both of which I want to access my web application and I have added the two groups (read/execute permissions) to my directory in IIS.  My web.config is pretty standard and I do not have any additional filters in my Global.asax file.

I am able to access my application if I use my user or admin account, but my coworker can not, which further complicates things.  My accounts do not have any permissions on the folder - only the groups to which they belong.

Authentication mode is set to Windows, but unfortunately every attempt as my coworker to access the website fails with the following:

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

The "most likely cause" box suggests:

```
The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.
```

I just can not figure this out.  If I create a sample mvc3 application and deploy it in the same directory, I can authenticate and view pages fine as any user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many reasons for this.

1. Your controller needs to be decorated with appropriate authorization attribute like following

   [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
2. In your web.config, you need to have following code inside your system.web configuration

   `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="YourRoleProvider">`
3. Finally you need to see if that user has been added to their respective roles

Comment: Chalk this up to a post-Holiday sanfu.  I had locked my controller function down too tightly.  Once to added the groups to my AuthorizeAttribute in global.asax and removed the Authorize from the controller, all was well!

Answer (score 1):

I'd the exact same issue. After having few hours of research, it seems to be very easy way to deal with this issue.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />-->
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I'd to remove `<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />` statement from *modules* attribute in Web.config file which was added by default while creating default MVC website.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in MVC 4, and I have resolved it with this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

(Add this line in controller, above action you are calling when this error appears.)